# Получить доступ к константам Joomla

Tags: php, joomla

Есть скрипт в папке с Joomla, точнее */var/www/html/joomla/images/file.php*. Как с этого файла получить доступ к константам джумлы, например к JPATH_ROOT

Comment: Константы Joomla доступны везде где загружается сам Framework, так же и в file.php

Comment: если написать echo JPATH_ROOT то оно не выведет путь к директории, а просто напишет 'JPATH_ROOT'

Comment: вы что то не так делаете, можете показать сам код ?

Comment: <?php
echo JPATH_ROOT;
?>

Comment: диагноз понятен, получается вы поставили file.php в директорию Root->images ? я правильно понял ?

Comment: да, root  папка joomla -> /images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Константы в `Joomla! framework` доступны везде где подключается сам движок, т.к вы установили файл `file.php` в директорию `images`, понятно что там константы не подгружаются, это просто директория... для того чтобы подгрузить сам `framework` в нестандартный файл, вам необходимо использовать следующий код (вставить в начало файла `file.php`):

```
$my_path = dirname(__FILE__);
$absolute_path = dirname( $my_path."/../configuration.php" );
/*
 /../ -  может изменяться в зависемости от количества директорий до root 
*/
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );
define( 'JPATH_BASE', $absolute_path );
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );

require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'defines.php' );
require_once ( JPATH_BASE . DS . 'includes' . DS . 'framework.php' );

$mainframe = JFactory::getApplication( 'site' );
```

После этого кода вы сможете использовать константы (и не только).

Comment: /*/../ -  может изменяться в зависемости от количества директорий до root*/ изменения будут происходить автоматически или нужно прописывать "../" самому?

Comment: Если вы меняете расположение файла, например переносите в глубь на одну директорию, то надо отредактировать путь и вставить /../../  т.е получится файл находится через две директории от configuration.php

Comment: $absolute_path принимает такое значение: " /var/www/html/joomla/images/.. ", не выходит из директории

Comment: Если вы вставили file.php в images, то $absolute_path должен иметь вид : /var/www/html/joomla/images/../configuration.php

Comment: $absolute_path не может подключить configuration.php т.к. не возвращается из директории в папку с configuration.php, то есть root

Comment: > не возвращается из директории в папку. почему не возвращается ?

Comment: JPATH_BASE == /var/www/html/joomla/images/.. а не /var/www/html/joomla

Comment: я бы посоветовал вам почитать о php директориях, после вам понятно будет что и как работает, в данном примере JPATH_BASE должен получать  /var/www/html/joomla/images/../ но не  /var/www/html/joomla  , /../ это означает переход на один уровень выше

Comment: 1000 извинений, все работает, эт я натупил. А есть способ подключения configuration.php не зависимо от глубины вложености скрипта который выполняется, file.php

Comment: Нет, и непонятно зачем вам необходимо динамически менять расположение файла, если вы собираетесь динамически копировать данный файл и вставлять в разных местах - я бы посоветовал так не делать

Comment: хотелось бы иметь универсальный способ, чтобы каждый раз в каком-то файле не писать ../../../